# Open cv face preprocessing not working in java

Tags: java, opencv, face-recognition

I am working on face recognition using java library of open cv. I got stuck on face pre processsing phase. here is my code-

```
double desiredFaceHeight=70;
double desiredFaceWidth=70;
double desiredLen=(DESIRED_RIGHT_EYE_X-0.16);
try{
double dy= (face.getRightEye().y-face.getLeftEye().y);
double dx= (face.getRightEye().x-face.getLeftEye().x);
double len=Math.sqrt((dx*dx)+(dy*dy));
double scale=desiredLen*desiredFaceWidth/len;
// Get the transformation matrix for the desired angle & size.
Mat rotMat=Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(face.getCenterOfEyes(),face.getEyesAngle(), scale);

//Shift the center of the eyes to be the desired center.
double ex= desiredFaceWidth*0.5f-face.getCenterOfEyes().x;
double ey=desiredFaceHeight*DESIRED_LEFT_EYE_Y-face.getCenterOfEyes().y;
rotMat.put(0,2,rotMat.get(0,2)[0]+ex);//view
rotMat.put(1,2,rotMat.get(1,2)[0]+ey);//view

Mat warped = new Mat((int)desiredFaceHeight, (int)desiredFaceWidth,CvType.CV_8U,new Scalar(128));
//Mat warped=face.getFace();
Imgproc.warpAffine(face.getFace(),warped, rotMat, warped.size());
```

but it does not gives transformed face. please describe what's wrong I am doing or provide an alternative solution. Thank you.

Comment: Please give a minimal Example of working (compiling) Code that shows your Problem and please try to write readable Code. You also might want to add some information about what it is that is not working.

Comment: By looking the code in to depth I came to know that the rotation part is not working.                                                        'Mat rotMat=Imgproc.getRotationMatrix2D(face.getCenterOfEyes(),face.getEyesAngle(), scale);'   Imgproc.warpAffine(face.getFace(),warped, rotMat, warped.size());

Comment: As far as I think the center about which the face is rotated is calculated wrongly.